# Standard Form Submit vs Ajax Form Submit - Browser Auto Save/Suggest User Input

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, submit

Most of us that use forms combined with ajax probably noticed that the input submitted by the user is not saved/suggested by the browser in later sessions. This is a downfall when it comes to 'sign in' pages. The browser usually offers to save the username/password, which is very handy, yet with an ajax form submit ....well, you know, this just doesn't happen.

I've seen this question twice on here and still no answers.  Its been about 9 months since it was asked, and I know there is a lot of smart people around here. So....I have decided to resurrect this question.

What can we do to resolve this?
Can we trick the browser somehow?

I am willing to work back and forth on this since I know it would be nice to have a working solution for all of us to use.

**Final Solution based off the answer from *slashingweapon*** (Thanks Man!)

**HTML** - Using a custom button to submit, along with no form 'action' or 'method', only ajax

```
<form id="signin">

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password"  name="password" />

    //Custom Styled Submit Button
    <img id="submit" class="form_button" src="btn_txt_sign_in.png" alt="Sign In" tabindex="3" />

    //Hidden Standard Form Submit Button
    <input id='trigger' type='submit' style='display:none;' />

</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
// Bind a click to the Custom Submit Button
$('#submit').click( function() {
    //Trigger a Click on the Hidden Standard Form Submit 
    $('#trigger').click();
});

// Detect when the form attempts to be submitted
$('#signin').submit( function(e){
    // Prevent Standard Form Submission
    e.preventDefault();
    // Perform Function containing Ajax Submission instead
    submit_signin();
});

// Ajax Submission
function submit_signin() {
    //My Ajax Call....
}
```

Comment: How are you submitting your forms? Binding to the form's `submit` event and usig AJAX there works for me ...

Comment: @JanHančič I am using serialize to grab the data from the form, and posting via ajax. I am not using a 'method' or 'action' for the form itself since the page should not be reloaded or travel to another page. The forms are in essence, just used to capture input, and the Ajax is used to post the data to a PHP and return the results dynamically.

Comment: I think what Jan was asking is, What event are you using to indicate form submission?  Are you using a submit event?  Or a button click event?

Comment: @slashingweapon I am using a click event on a custom button. I am not using the standard <input type='submit'>

Comment: Use a submit button instead of a custom one.  Catch the form's submit event instead of the button click event.

Comment: @slashingweapon On one hand, I get what your saying, on the other, the form should be submitted only through an ajax call, not actually submit the form via 'action' & 'method'. Can you post an answer to show what you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When any button of type submit is clicked, the enclosing form is submitted.  You can choose to handle the submit event instead of the button's click event.  Here is an example:

```
$('#demoForm').submit(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    alert(data);
});​
```

There's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sr2Ft/) for you, too.

By catching the later event, you'll ensure that at least some browsers have a chance to store the form data for future auto-fills.

Comment: This makes sense..does it matter whether I use the submit input or submit button? I take it as long as I am using type='submit' I should be good...correct? I assume too that I could use a custom button/click to trigger the submit button...

Comment: I am going to implement this later on and see the results. I'll accept the answer if all goes well.  And thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is any real difference between the input element and the button element in this case.

Comment: This seems to work in the latest version of FireFox (24.0) but not Chrome (30.0.1599.101)